# Remember my login for a longer time on Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, login, data-explorer

For some reason, I have to login again whenever I haven't touched the data explorer for some unreasonably small period of time (<<< 1 day).

I am logged in with the StackExchange openid.

I usually end up entering the captcha instead when it's just a quick query.

Firefox 37.